# Why doesn't my css work when I check my theme on mobile devices?

Tags: theme-development, css

I am currently in the process of creating my first WordPress theme, and it is going okay, but I have run into an issue. When I try to view my site on either of my mobile devices (tablet and phone) my css is not working.

I am connected to the internet on both devices, and am routing myself to the IP address of my local machine which has an AMPPS server running, but when I open my WordPress folder in my directory, it is just the html content of my theme.

I have checked the other folders in my directory to make sure it was only an issue with this one project and it was. This is the only WordPress theme I am developing.

Is there something I am missing for WordPress theme development regarding css for mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the approach a bit. You know that is easier to solve the maze if you go from the end to the beginning.

Why don't you copy the CSS styles from some newly created theme like 2017-teen for your theme, and later improve? It should work.

You can start with the templates you created, or try to create the templates based on 2017-teen.

Take the best girl you can and provide her your dressing.

---

You can use the customizer to check.

[image]

---

Also, make sure you use the css that is super portable. 
http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I tried changing the theme to a pre built theme and viewing it on my mobile devices but that does not work either. I know that my css works and is valid because I can see it in action on my desktop browser. There is just something missing when I go to view my theme on any mobile device.

Comment: What is "pre built theme"? @hoolakoola

Comment: Sorry, a stock theme that has already been built. I tried Twenty Fourteen and Twenty Sixteen but the css for those does not work on my mobile devices either.

Comment: Can I ask what mobile devices you use so 2016-teen is not working?...

Comment: I have a Galaxy S6 and a 2015 Ipad Mini.. This is on my local environment though. When I select any theme and view it on my desktop browser it works fine. When I try to view any theme through my mobile device the css is not working.

Comment: But all of my other projects (non wordpress) render the css and correctly.

Comment: I added one image to my answer. This is a custmizer in the Dashboard of WordPress. Can you enter the WordPress customizer by click the Customize button and try to switch to the mobile view?

Comment: I would like if you can tell me if it works that way ?

Comment: Yes my css is working when I do that.

Comment: I must admit I don't have the idea what is wrong in that case. Very sorry. I will mark this question and follow.  Fingers crossed.

Comment: BTW some CSS will not work inside mobiles. Let me pull the site...

Comment: No worries. Thanks for reminding me I could use the customizer to view it. Now I can at least check on my designs until I get this figured out.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/